# Getting the last result using LIMIT in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a table that is similar to the one below, my goal is to LIMIT the result to 10 AND THEN return the id of the LAST result which is 10. I've tried doing, the query below but it keeps returning my the value of 15, instead of 10.

```
SELECT id FROM this_table WHERE value=value ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10.  

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: This query will not return just `15`. It will return ten rows, with `15`,`14`,...,`6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(id) from
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM this_table 
    WHERE value = 'some_value'
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 10
) x
```

Comment: I need the condition WHERE though

Comment: That condition is always true. value is always = value

Comment: Nope, the one I wrote above was just an exapmple

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I'll mark your answer correct in 5 min

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` can take two parameters.

Try

```
SELECT id FROM this_table WHERE value=value 
ORDER BY id LIMIT 9,1
```

[Read all about it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

**EDIT**: Oh, and loose the `DESC` part. It seems you don't really need it.